# Can't properly send JSON to server in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, network-programming

So I have a prebuilt server, designed for my class (school class, not code) and I know it works because other people are able to use it.

I am trying to use UnityWebRequest to send a JSON string to the server, but it doesn't appear to be sending.  The server is listening on 127.0.0.1:8000 and I used the URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000" in Unity.

```
public class NetworkTest : MonoBehaviour

{
  void Start()
  {
    string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
    Base message = new Base();
    Data data = new Data();
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    message.messageType = "connect";
    data.game = "default";
    data.clientType = "client";
    conf.id = "test";
    data.configuration = conf;
    message.data = data;

    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(message);
    Debug.Log("Json: " + json);
    StartCoroutine(Post(url, json));
  }

  IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString)
  {
    var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
    request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.timeout = 20;

    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.data);
    Debug.Log("after sendrequest");

    Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);
  }


}
```

The code runs fine, but I just get Status Code: 0 every time.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: So in the server's verbose mode, it does notice a connection come in from the code, but I don't seem to ger a reply on the client-side.  The server also doesn't seem to be accepting the JSON and acknowledging the client is sending data, just connecting.  Also, what does /wd/hub do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I couldn't edit original comment. It's an example of a potential endpoint that could exist at the server / port address. Is the server configured to accept requests to specific endpoints like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/some/endpoint` ?

Comment: are you sure that your server accepts requests with Content-Type `application/json`?, As @Christine mentioned are sure about the endpoint url?
You can test your server with https://www.getpostman.com/